# L2 instruction fetch misses much higher than L1 instruction fetch misses

Tags: performance, intel, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, perf

I am generating a synthetic C benchmark aimed at causing a large number of instruction fetch misses via the following Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tempfile
import random
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    functions = list()

    for i in range(10000):
        func_name = "f_{}".format(next(tempfile._get_candidate_names()))
        sys.stdout.write("void {}() {{\n".format(func_name))
        sys.stdout.write("    double pi = 3.14, r = 50, h = 100, e = 2.7, res;\n")
        sys.stdout.write("    res = pi*r*r*h;\n")
        sys.stdout.write("    res = res/(e*e);\n")
        sys.stdout.write("}\n")
        functions.append(func_name)


    sys.stdout.write("int main() {\n")
    sys.stdout.write("unsigned int i;\n")
    sys.stdout.write("for(i =0 ; i < 100000 ;i ++ ){\n")
    for i in range(10000):
        r = random.randint(0, len(functions)-1)
        sys.stdout.write("{}();\n".format(functions[r]))


    sys.stdout.write("}\n")
    sys.stdout.write("}\n")
```

What the code does is simply generating a **C program** that consists of a lot of randomly named dummy functions that are in turn called in random order in `main()`. I am compiling the resulting code with gcc 4.8.5 under CentOS 7 with `-O0`. The code is running on a dual socket machine fitted with 2x Intel Xeon E5-2630v3 (Haswell architecture).

What I am interested in is understanding instruction-related counters reported by perf when profiling the **binary compiled from the C code** (not the Python script, that is only used to automatically generate the code). In particular, I am observing the following counters with `perf stat`:

- **instructions**
- **L1-icache-load-misses** (instruction fetches that miss L1, aka r0280 on Haswell)
- **r2424**, **L2_RQSTS.CODE_RD_MISS** (instruction fetches that miss L2)
- **rf824**, **L2_RQSTS.ALL_PF** (all L2 hardware prefetcher requests, both code and data)

I first profiled the code with all hardware prefetchers disabled in the BIOS, i.e.

- MLC Streamer Disabled
- MLC Spatial Prefetcher Disabled
- DCU Data Prefetcher Disabled
- DCU Instruction Prefetcher Disabled

and the results are the following (process is pinned to first core of second CPU and corresponding NUMA domain, but I guess this doesn't make much difference):

```
perf stat -e instructions,L1-icache-load-misses,r2424,rf824 numactl --physcpubind=8 --membind=1 /tmp/code   

 Performance counter stats for 'numactl --physcpubind=8 --membind=1 /tmp/code':    

    25,108,610,204      instructions                                               
     2,613,075,664      L1-icache-load-misses                                       
     5,065,167,059      r2424                                                       
                17      rf824                                                       

      33.696954142 seconds time elapsed
```

Considering the figures above, I cannot explain such a high number of instruction fetch misses in L2. I have disabled all prefetchers, and **L2_RQSTS.ALL_PF** confirms so. But why do I see twice as much the number of instruction fetch misses in L2 than in L1i? In my (simple) mental processor model, if an instruction is looked up in L2, it must have necessarily been looked up in L1i before. Clearly I am wrong, what am I missing?

I then tried to run the same code with all the hardware prefetchers enabled, i.e.

- MLC Streamer Enabled
- MLC Spatial Prefetcher Enabled
- DCU Data Prefetcher Enabled
- DCU Instruction Prefetcher Enabled

and the results are the following:

```
perf stat -e instructions,L1-icache-load-misses,r2424,rf824 numactl --physcpubind=8 --membind=1 /tmp/code

 Performance counter stats for 'numactl --physcpubind=8 --membind=1 /tmp/code':    

    25,109,877,626      instructions                                               
     2,599,883,072      L1-icache-load-misses                                       
     5,054,883,231      r2424                                                       
           908,494      rf824
```

Now, **L2_RQSTS.ALL_PF** seems to indicate that something more is happening and although I expected the prefetcher to be a bit more aggressive, I imagine that the instruction prefetcher is severely put to the test due to the jump-intensive type of workload and data prefetcher has not much to do with this kind of workload. But again, **L2_RQSTS.CODE_RD_MISS** is still too high with the prefetchers enabled.

So, to sum up, my question is:

With hardware prefetchers disabled, **L2_RQSTS.CODE_RD_MISS** seems to be much higher than **L1-icache-load-misses**. Even with hardware prefetchers enabled, I still cannot explain it. What is the reason behind such a high count of **L2_RQSTS.CODE_RD_MISS** compared to **L1-icache-load-misses**?

Comment: Two questions: 1. Are you able to verify that all the misses are from your synthetic benchmark ? 2. Is the L2 cache connected to more than one L1 cache?

Comment: Although it is unlikely, can your L1 cache line size is bigger than L2 cache line size?

Comment: Check MSR 0x1A4 - https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/disclosure-of-hw-prefetcher-control-on-some-intel-processors - "..Haswell.. support 4 types of h/w prefetchers for prefetching data".."**L2 adjacent cache line prefetcher**" may do "Fetches the cache line that comprises a cache line pair (128 bytes)". (Also, can you compute how much memory are used for instructions to convert 25 G instr into bytes and cache lines). Isuru, this is Haswell with small 256KB unified L2 https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/HSW_IMG_4.png for every CPU core (only L3 is shared between cores)

Comment: The prefetcher that loads L2 adjacent cache lines is the **MLC Spatial Prefetcher**, and I have complete control over it in the BIOS. As per the average number of instructions per cache line, I would say 10 to 14. With all prefetchers disabled, 10 instructions seems about right, 14 a bit high, but this code jumps a lot, I expect a significant number of evictions with a 32KiB L1i, after all, that was the point of the code.

Comment: You are profiling the python interpreter, not the code.   Sure, L2-misses are going to be high, you are seeing the interpreter getting loaded and initialized.  You can only get meaningful numbers when you record the perf counters before and after the loops.  Well, not so easy to do in Python perhaps.

Comment: You did not read carefully my question. The Python code generates C code that is compiled with gcc. The C code is what I am profiling, I am perfectly aware that it doesn't make sense to profile PyEval_EvalFrameEx.

Comment: I'm a little more weary of the -O0 compilation, while it's not related to the weird perf counters results, it could make your program do completely different things than you expect. Does this reproduce with -O3?

Comment: @MarcoGuerri, Can you check real value of 0x1A4 MSR and 0x1A0 MSR and post them here? (Is there any prefetch engine enabled in L1i?)

Comment: @osgx With hardware prefetchers disabled, 0x1A4 is 0xF (all set, all disabled). If I try to re-enable MLC Spatial Prefetcher, I get 0xD, i.e. second bit cleared (adjacent prefetcher according to Intel page). As for 0x1A0, from a quick look at Intel docs it seems that register controls prefetchers only on the Core microarchitecture. Anyway, all cores are set to 0x850089. @Leeor If I compile the code with -O3, the compiler basically optimizes everything away, each function becomes simply a ```ret``` and the code terminates in few milliseconds.

Comment: Marco, And what is the value of 0x1a0?

Comment: All the cores report 0x850089 for 0x1A0

Comment: @MarcoGuerri, make the function return `res`, then the compiler won't optimize the loop away

Comment: @MarcoGuerri I have met the same problem, just wonder if you have figured out the   reason finally?

Comment: @YiZhenfei: it has been a long time. Unfortunately, I did not come to any conclusion back then.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction prefetcher can generate requests are that don't count as accesses to the L1I cache, but are counted as code fetch requests at higher-numbered memory levels, such as the L2. This is generally true on all Intel microarchitectures with an instruction prefetcher. `L2_RQSTS.CODE_RD_MISS` counts both demand and prefetch requests from the L1I. Demand requests are generated by a multiplexing unit in the IFU that chooses a target fetch linear address from among the different units in the pipeline that may change the flow, such as the branch prediction units. Prefetch requests are generated by the L1I instruction prefetcher on an L1I miss if possible.

In general, the number of prefetch fetch requests is nearly proportional to the number of L1I misses. For instruction fetches from memory regions of cacheable memory types, the following formula holds:

`ICACHE.MISSES` <= `L2_RQSTS.CODE_RD_MISS` + `L2_RQSTS.CODE_RD_HIT`

I'm not sure whether this formula also holds for uncacheable fetch requests. I didn't test it in that condition. I know these requests are counted as `ICACHE.MISSES`, but not sure about the other events.

In your case, most instruction fetches will miss in the L1I and L2. You have 10,000 functions each nearly fully spans 2 64-btye cache lines ([here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4Tsq5h) is a version with only two functions), so the code size is much larger than the 256 KiB L2 available on Haswell. The functions are being called in a non-sequential and upredictable order, so the L1I and L2 prefetchers won't significantly help. The only noteworthy exception are returns, all of which will be predicted correctly using the RSB mechanism.

Each of the 10,000 functions are being called 100,000 times in a loop. Most fetch requests are for lines occupied by these functions. The total number of useful instruction fetch requests is about 2 lines per function * 10,000 function * 100,000 iterations = 2,000,000,000 lines, most of which will miss in the L1I and L2 (but probably hit in the L3 after the first cold iteration). Several millions of other requests will be for lines occupied by the loop body. Your measurements show that there are about 30% more instruction fetches that miss in the L1I. This is because of branch mispredictions, which cause fetch requests for incorrect lines that may not be even be in the L1I and/or L2. Each L1I miss may trigger a prefetch, so it's normal for L2 instruction fetches to be within two times the number of L1I misses. This is consistent with your numbers.

In my two-function [version](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4Tsq5h), I'm counting 24 instructions per invoked function, so I expect the total number of retired instructions to be approximately 24 billion, but you got 25 billion. Either I don't know how to count, or you have 25 instructions per function for some reason.